# Simple variables in AS3 not increasing properly

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

Alright, so i've got some code that says that if a hit test is preformed, a variable is increased by 1. However, when I run it, I get crazy numbers like 1,1,1,2,5,3,2,5,2,3,4,1,1
There's no pattern, it's just random. Here's the code:

```
public function loop(e:Event)
{
    y +=  speed;



    if (y > stage.stageHeight)
    {
        setupAsteroid(false);
    }

    //hittest for the asteroid

    if (hitTestObject(target))
    {
        stageRef.addChild(new Explosion(stageRef, x, y));
        trace("Hit");
        kills ++;
        trace(kills);
        if(kills == 3){
            trace("Success");
        }
}
```

I've included all the code in the function used, and not all of it is necessary to the hit test as you can see. also, the variable is declared correctly as

```
private var kills:Number = 0;
```

inside the same .as file and class.

Comment: I have no idea if this will fix the problem (probably not), but I'd recommend to write `kills++;` without the space. That's how it's usually done and even if it makes no difference, it's easier (for me at least) to read. Also, again just a tip, if `kills` is always a whole number, you might want to define it as `int` instead of `Number`.

Comment: @puggsoy spacing doesn't matter, it could be placed before or after with or without a space. ++kills; ++ kills; kills++; kills       + would all work the same. Also you might as well use uint instead of int :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a for loop amongst multiple targets?

Comment: @puggsoy, thanks for the tips, but they didn't solve the issues.

Comment: @mika I'm sure. In fact I haven't even written any for loops in the game yet. It's  in a very basic stage right now.

Comment: what is target? you should put the full source on a gist: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Try to define a function setting kills's value,set you can debug how kills changes. I guess you have set kills's value in other place.

Comment: I expect `setupAsteroid` resets `kills` to zero, and since your asteroid is the only one, its kills then start from one. Also, if you have multiple asteroids, you'll surely have a mess. Try `trace(this.name, kills)` instead of tracing kills only, and watch the name if it's one and only.

Comment: As @Vesper suggested it's likely that you are listening for this `enterFrame` event in a wrong place, like in a class of an `Asteroid` and since you create multiple instances of that class you get that "crazy" numbers. Try having a one `enterFrame` listener in your game class and do all the collisions there.

Answer (score 0):

You add an `Explosion` to the stage but there is no sign of you removing anything from the stage, or at least stopping the check for `hitTest`. Also I'm guessing that your function `loop(e:Event)` listens for an `ENTER_FRAME` event and in that case if you're not removing anything from the stage that `hitTest` is going to be returning true every frame and creating a new `Explosion` every frame. Why not just add a public variable to target, like `public var destroyed:boolean = false;` and reconstruct your `hitTest` to read `if(hitTestObject(target) && !target.destroyed)` and in the body of your conditional just add `target.destroyed = true;`

More code would definitely help though.